# Enforce FLS/CRUD Delete issue in security scan

Tags: security-review, fls, crud

I am getting problem in understanding a issue given by security scan.

The problem is :

[[image: Not able to understand CRUD Delete result path 2:]]

I am not pasting the whole code but the essential lines:

```
public with sharing class C62AccountsPayableController {

public VendorInvoiceWrapper cSelVI {get;set;}
public List<VendorInvoiceWrapper> viList{get;set;}

 public class VendorInvoiceWrapper{
        public List<Vendor_Invoice_Line__c> delete_lines{get;set;}
 }

 public void saveVI(){
   for(VendorInvoiceWrapper vi : viList){
   if(Schema.sObjectType.Vendor_Invoice_Line__c.isDeletable())                             {delete cSelVI.delete_lines;}
   vi.delete_lines.clear();
   }
}
```

Anybody have idea about it why its giving issue in this line.I am thinking its because of list I am passing to delete.But still why it would be an issue to pass a list.

Comment: What issue you you are facing ? could you please add more details here! or exactly what issue has been reported by security scanner?

Answer (score 0):

You can report it as a false positive, although I can't figure out why you are still receiving the issue even though you have added a CRUD check.

Please look at this question this might help you:-
[Security scanner: enforcing CRUD. Auto scanner reported issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143518/security-scanner-enforcing-crud-auto-scanner-reported-issue)

Thanks,
Nachiket